# Dojo : how to set to disable new button

Tags: button, dojo

Hi I have trouble setting the new button to disabled. 
I am using Dojo 1.8

See my code below:-

```javascript
require(["dojo/parser", "dijit/layout/BorderContainer",
"dijit/form/Button","dojo/on","dijit/form/Select",
"dojo/store/Memory", "dojo/request","dojo/domReady!"
],
function(parser, BorderContainer, Button, on, Select, Memory, request)
{

var btn4 = new Button // Button, not button
({
    label: "Number of cards",
    this.set("disabled", false) // This code that disables the button
    },"btn4"); 
btn4.startup();
})
```

I cannot find help in Dojo or google for it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, trying to call `this.set()` within the argument list of a dijit does not make sense because the dijit has not been created yet.  Second, the first parameter to a dijit is always a standard javascript object with key/value pairs.  Trying to insert a function call in the middle of an object declaration is simply a syntax error in the code itself.

Finally, there is no need to try using the dijit's setter at all. Just set `disabled: true` in your argument list to the `Button` dijit.

```javascript
var btn4 = new Button({
    label: "Number of cards",
    disabled: true,
}, "btn4");
```

See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GBZKn/2/).

Answer (score 16):

In Dojo many things are other as you would expect.

Button have method `setDisabled`:

```javascript
btn4.setDisabled(true) // disable
btn4.setDisabled(false) // enable
```

Comment: Amazingly, you are right. I could disable a button with button.set('disabled', true) but could not re-enable it with button.set('disabled', false) -- it seems to cast false => null somewhere. The button.setDisabled(false) method works. I assume that this is a dojo bug.